# self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options) _tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "image1.png" - Unable to load png

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I'm trying to make an app using Python and Tkinter but I'm not able to load an image, or png to be specific. Instead, I'm getting this long error:

```
 File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4038, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "image1.png".
```

Can someone help me fix this? Here are the lines of code that might be causing the error:

```
cycle1IMG = tk.PhotoImage(file="image1.png")

def openNewWindow1():
    newWindow = Toplevel(master)
    newWindow.title("Cycle 1")
    newWindow.geometry("750x500")
    Label(newWindow, text="Cycle 1", image= cycle1IMG).pack()

cycle1 =tk.Button(
    root,
    text="Cycle 1",
    command=openNewWindow1
    
)
cycle1.place(x=500,y=300)
```

Comment: This is telling you that your png file doesn't contain png data. Did you take an image of some other type (eg: .gif or jpeg, for example) and just rename the file to .png? That's usually the cause of this type of error.

Comment: Yes, I changed it from a .webp file to a .png file, but the .webp file doesn't seem to be working either.

Comment: tkinter doesn't work with `webp`. And first you should check if your file is really `png`. Maybe it is `webp` with extension `.png`. OR maybe you have totally different file (ie, text file) with extension `.png`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a comment to the question, it appears that you took a .webp file and just renamed it to .png. This doesn't change the internal contents of the file, which is why tkinter reported the error: you told it to open a .png file but the contents of the file isn't in the png format.

Tkinter doesn't support webp. You'll have to use some other library to read the file and convert it to a format supported by tkinter (eg: [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/))